# Installing a package with Ansible and not starting the service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, ansible

I have the following play snippet:

```
 27   - name: ensure necessary packages are installed
 28     apt:
 29       state: present
 30       name:
 31         - apache2
 32         - libapache2-mod-rpaf
 33         - nginx
```

I don't run IPv6 (LAN) so I have `ipv6.disable=1` in my boot args.   When Ansible installs Nginx, it defaults to listening on `listen [::]:80 default_server;` and returns an error in the play.  How can I tell Ansible/apt not to start Nginx (or any service for that matter.. probably the same story with Apache) when installing the package?

Comment: This is a long standing design flaw with Debian and Debian-based systems. Ansible cannot really fix it or even work around it. Have you considered using another distro? In the meantime see the workarounds in the linked question.

Comment: Ha ha /s.. Yes.  And they all have their fair share of things that suck about them. Seriously no way to disable that (aside from hackery)?

Comment: Nope...and sometimes the hackery doesn't work either. They do this intentionally. I've finally eradicated all trace of Debian from my production environments...

Comment: Ugh.. alright. Thanks for the info.

Comment: For anyone else running into this.. I ended up adding the `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` hack linked above and then only installing `apache` and `nginx` in a play right after that. Very next play removes `policy-rc.d` so any other packages installed can behave normally.